# PostgreSQL cube query optimisation

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT
    recipe_id,
    macros,
    cube_distance (macros,
        CUBE (ARRAY [968, 68, 78, 39])) AS distance
FROM
    indexable_recipes
ORDER BY
    distance
LIMIT 50;
```

Which on my local machine executes in ~230ms on a table with around 400k rows.

I would like any advices you guys might have, in order to optimise the query, as I'm new to postgis and don't know much about all the available functions etc.

Also, if anyone can help me out changing the query a bit, it would be great. What I really want, rather than the current limit ordered bv distance, I want no limit, but instead I need to filter on the distance and then DISTINCT recipe_id. When I tried with distinct, I didn't get the best match for the entry, I assume I just got the first match.

**So what I need is:**

- select some columns based on the CUBE array, calculated with distance
- get only unique items (recipe_id)
- remove LIMIT and instead only get all results with a distance < 10

And also, if there's any other things I can do to optimise speed, like indexes or such, it would be appreciated :)

EXPLAIN of the query:

```
Limit  (cost=28092.07..28097.90 rows=50 width=56)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=28092.07..75324.37 rows=404820 width=56)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=27092.04..27598.07 rows=202410 width=56)
"              Sort Key: (cube_distance(macros, '(968, 68, 78, 39)'::cube))"
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on indexable_recipes  (cost=0.00..20368.13 rows=202410 width=56)
```

Comment: Start by running  `EXPLAIN` and see what's going on.

Comment: Added the output to the question :)

Comment: I am not at all an expert on optimization on any platform.  You may want to play with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE`, and [this tool](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new) gives a visualization of the joins and timings.  `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` will tell you more about the timings of things.

Comment: See also on [reading query plans](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/reading-an-explain-analyze-query-plan), [performance considerations](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/postgresql-performance-considerations), and [advanced performance tips](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/advanced-postgres-performance-tips).